# Create an array images to make movement in C#

Tags: c#, soundplayer

How to create movement in C# with images?
Now I am creating a snake game. Snake is made by 3 parts: head, body and tail. How to link three parts and make movement smoth?
Thank you so much

Comment: Did you add the file to your resources directory ?

Comment: the path I put the file is bin/Debug/effectSound/Eat.wav

Comment: Then it won't be in your resources directory, see the linked question it should give you a couple of ways to do what you are wanting.

Comment: I tried put the file as the example in the Internet and the project of my trainer(create a folder resources , then add files to this with path: player.SoundLocation = (@"resources/Eat.wav");
   player.Load(); ), but it did not work

Comment: ht? What does ht mean? @.@

Comment: Sorry Typo. You need to create a resource directory, you haven't.  Look at the answers in the duplicate question.

Comment: I could not find any question which is same or has the good solution for me! @.@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard .NET System.IO method `File.Exists(path)` as explained in MSDN documentation online: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx .

Also useful can be multiple `System.IO` `Path` methods (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope this may help. Kind regards,

Comment: Thank you so much! :D Let me try!

Comment: You are welcome! If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it accepted. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: I have already added library System.IO, but, it still notified error, Plz, give me the right path. What folder should I put the sound file in?

Comment: I apologize, but it seems that this question is already closed by other folks. Would you please post another question if you have any? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Yep, I will add another question. Thank you so much

Comment: my question is complained ,therefore, I cannot upload any question more! @.@

Comment: It's a general rule of how the system works. I would recommend you to read that referenced post; it contains plenty of useful information pertinent to your question. Best regards,